# Gemfile constants redefinition, "warning: already initialized constant"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, constants, gemfile

In my `Gemfile` I have two gems that both define the same set of constants. The two gems are `sentiment_lib` and `engtagger`.

This means whenever I run a task I get more than 10 warnings like this:

```
...engtagger/porter.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Stemmable::STEP_2_LIST
...stemmer/porter.rb:10: warning: previous definition of STEP_2_LIST was here
```

Since the same file is just used in both it's not been an issue - but the warnings are starting to get annoying.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What's inside porter.rb, is it a class or module? and what's the path to it? Run bundle show entagger

Comment: Same as https://github.com/yohasebe/engtagger/blob/master/lib/engtagger/porter.rb stemmer one is effectively identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by forking `engtagger`
Then remove the file with the constant that's already been initiated through the other gem, commit your changes to the newly created fork.

Add it to your Gemfile

```
gem engtagger, github: 'your_github_handle/engtagger'
```

Then run `bundle update engtagger`

Now you should have engtagger in your bundle without that module.

If we weren't dealing with constants, I would recommend a module eval, but it most likely won't work, since constants once set, can't be change, hence the warning message.

Comment: Cool - I was hoping there would be an easier way. I'm going to leave the answer unaccepted just in case there are any other suggestions. If not I'll accept it later. Thanks.

Comment: For sure, there are a few other ways, but dealing with constants can be difficult, I'd love to know if there's an easier way as well